# css internet explorer hacks

Tags: css, internet-explorer, joomla

Im using a rockettheme template and have edited some of the css code using a custom css file.

I have managed to get it how I want it to look on Firefox and Chrome however IE looks werid. the navigation is too low (the buttons) and the header is also too low.

The website link is found below.

http://www.colmanprint.co.nz/rfloorings/

as you can see on the link the menubar is down too low and the header.

at the moment im using a css code edit .rt-menubar {padding: 0px !important; margin-left:210px;} when i remove the margin-left:210px; it fixes my problem but then the menu goes behind the logo on chrome and firefox.

so i pretty much need to keep the margin-left:210px for chrome and firefox but have margin-left:0px for internet explorer

any ideas would be great!

Comment: Are you having a problem in IE10 or 9?

Comment: To be honest I dont know - Its probably all IE browsers but I use IE 8.

Comment: For IE9 and before, you can use Conditional comments - place separate CSS inside for IE. For IE10, you could possibly use Modernizr.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply - do you know what the code will be Ive googled a few things but with no luck - I feel like im doing something wrong

Comment: are you meaning <!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]--> if so I have tried this and with no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versions of Internet Explorer up to IE9, you could use [**conditional comments**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to differentiate between IE and other browsers.

Here's a quick example:

```
<!--[if IE]> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-below.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then in `ie9-and-below.css` you could apply a style such as:

```
#ieParagraph.rt-menubar {
   margin-left:0px;
}
```

Where your HTML could look like so:

```
<div class="rt-menubar" id="ieParagraph">
   <ul>Other stuff here...</ul>
</div>
```

If no styling was applied in your other stylesheets to `#ieParagraph` where the class was also `.rt-menubar` , this would only change the left margin of the `#ieParagraph` `div` to `0px` **in IE9 and under only**.

---

For IE10, conditional comments have been removed - look into using [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) for feature detection.

Comment: Thank you Zenith, I will give this a go - Would the same thing apply for margins? just create a new ie9-and-below.css and change the margin?

Comment: @Callum Where did you place the conditonal comments? Have you looked in f12 tools to check whether you element actually has the ieParagraph styling and if it's being over-ridden (crossed out)?

Comment: For rockettheme in joomla i went into Template Manager - and then under the main page template I placed the <!--[if IE]> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9-and-below.css" />
<![endif]--> - I then created a css and added #ieParagraph.rt-menubar {
   margin-left:0px;
}

Comment: the only thing is (and i should have explained better) is the main page template is php.

Comment: @Callum Sorry, I forgot about Joomla - is your CSS inline? If so you could use `<!--[if ie]> <div class="rt-menubar" style="margin-left:0px"> <![endif]--> <!--[if !ie]> <div class="rt-menubar" style="margin-left:210px"> <![endif]-->`. There are also a few examples of this in Joomla by Googling 'Joomla conditional comments'

Comment: Thanks Zenith, not too sure if css is inline or not. but i tried that code and didnt work - I will look into Joomla conditional comments. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Callum No worries, throw me a comment later if you manage a solution or not and I'll try fix up something

Comment: Hi Zenith, I thought I had it working but wasnt to be - Have you worked in Joomla before?